# SQL Order By Column If It Has Value

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by

I have the following table:

#### Objects (o)

```
id    name              date_completed
----------------------------------------
1     Computer          2016-02-26
2     Desk              NULL
3     Curtain           2016-02-25
```

I tried to use this query:

```
SELECT * FROM objects ORDER BY date_completed NULLS FIRST, name
```

And as expected I get this result:

```
id    name              date_completed
----------------------------------------
2     Desk              NULL
3     Curtain           2016-02-25
1     Computer          2016-02-26
```

I want the result to be ordered such that it doesn't order them by the actual date but instead put the ones with `NULL` in the `date_completed` at the top and order them by the name. And then put the ones with a value in the `date_completed` at the bottom and order them by the name as well.

Basically here's what I want to get:

```
id    name              date_completed
----------------------------------------
2     Desk              NULL
1     Computer          2016-02-26
3     Curtain           2016-02-25
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM objects 
ORDER BY (case when date_completed is null then 1 else 2 end),name
```

Comment: Oh wow, now that I see your solution I can't believe I didn't think of that.